# How to get Button Value from another class on android studio

Tags: java, android

I have 2 class, which the first class i created Loop button
and second class i want to get button value from first class..

Here is my code

```
public class FirstClass extends AppCompatActivity  {
public static Button[] btn = new Button[8];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlid);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    for(int i=0; i<btn.length; i++)
    {
        btn[i] = new Button(this);
        btn[i].setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        btn[i].setText((i + 0) + " ");

        btn[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
        relativeLayout.addView(btn[l]);
    }
}
}

public class SecondClass extends Activity {
Button btn2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Button bb = FirstClass.btn[2]; //get button no 2 from 1st class
            bb.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW); // try to change into yellow but nothing happen
        }
    });
```

Comment: may i know the reason for doing this

Comment: Your `btn` in your `FirstClass` are not added in activity's `contentView`, they are not showed in UI.

Answer (score 2):

Although bad practice of using views as static fields, your code should work.

Another problem is that you have created buttons in the first activity and done nothing with them. You should probably add them to some layout of the activity.

The good practice would be not to store buttons or any views in static fields, and get results using Intents. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html